# Searching in gridjs HTML fields

Tags: html, search, callback, gridjs

My table has nearly all columns filled with HTML links like

```
<a href="...">content</a>
```

How shoud I formulate the search function so that the normal gridjs search be executed also for those links considering only their content (and excluding the HTML stuff) ?

I tried to insert a search function like explained in the literarure but with no effort. Typing the keyword resulted in an empty result.